# Enforcing asynchronous computation for a list of objects

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a class that performs some *heavy* calculations. For a bunch of different inputs I would like to do those calculations in parallel in multiple threads, because they are independent from each other. How can I enforce that? I tried this code (dummy test from dotnetfiddle) but the calculations are already being done in the "list generation" instead of the `Task.AwaitAll`

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        List<Model> models = new List<Model>();
        for (int i = 100; i<10000; i++) {
            models.Add(new Model(i));
        }
        List<Task> list = new();
        /* assume list of model with different input sets */
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        foreach(var model in models)
        {
            list.Add(model.Calculate());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()); // here I would assume 0, but all the calculations are already done
        sw.Restart();
        await Task.WhenAll(list);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()); // yields almost 0
        
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public double Result {get; set;}
    public int input {get; set;}
    public Model(int Input)  {
        input = Input;
        Result = 0;
    }
    public Task Calculate() 
    {
        /* do "heavy" stuff */
        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
            Result += i;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a `Task` does not magically run the code on a new thread; in fact it indicates that the method is *asynchronous* rather than computationally expensive.

Regardless, `Calculate` has a completely synchronous implementation, and will run synchronously, irrespective of the `Task` being returned.

This being said, don't return a `Task` from `Calculate`.

If you want to use `Task`s to run calculations on separate threads, then there is [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run), which offloads work to the ThreadPool, and returns a `Task` representing that work.

An example:

```
foreach (var model in models)
{
    list.Add(Task.Run(model.Calculate));
}

await Task.WhenAll(list);
```

Or more concisely:

```
await Task.WhenAll(models.Select(model => Task.Run(model.Calculate)));
```

Although [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) is designed specifically for this purpose:

```
Parallel.ForEach(models, model => model.Calculate());
```

Comment: You could consider adding `.AsParallel()` for completeness

Comment: @JonasH There isn't a return value, so `AsParallel` probably isn't appropriate here.

Comment: I didn't know Parallel, that is awesome. Thank you

Comment: Ah, true. I might consider mentioning it anyway, since using a model-class with input and result properties seems weird to me, I would probably argue that the calculate method *should* take input and return results.